# How to load entire stream into MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Like in the topic: I want to read data from a file (from stream) into memory (memorystream) to improve my app speed. How to do it?

Comment: You can use the StreamReader.ReadToEnd method. This will read all the file to a string. Why do you want to read it to a stream? The streamReader uses a stream so you can read from it as you need and count on the framework to optimize things.

Comment: @AmiramKorach: For one thing, you're assuming this is text. StreamReader is *only* appropriate for text data.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

A few options:

**Read it all into a byte array first...**

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
```

**Or use .NET 4's CopyTo method**

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(file))
{
    input.CopyTo(memoryStream);
}
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

**Or do it manually**

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(file))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024]; // 32K buffer for example
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: I've noticed the first method `File.ReadAllBytes` behaves quite a lot different than the "CopyTo" method as far as memory consumption goes (.NET 4.5).  Specifically, reading dozens of files in a tight loop with `File.ReadAllBytes` memory isn't reclaimed as well as the `CopyTo` version.  Might be worth some more investigation.

Comment: Thank you, oddly CopyTo misbehaved for me, the final stream didn't see all the data. I used @Austin Salonen approach (with ReadAllBytes) and this one worked fine. Weird stuff...

Comment: @greenoldman: Without knowing more details, it's hard to say, but that sounds like maybe you'd already read some data from the stream first.

Comment: Oh, after some more testing I found out the culprit, this little fella resetting `Position` back to 0 after copying is crucial ;-) My bad, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 12):

If you can hold the entire file in memory, [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes) should work for you:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
{
    // do work
}
```