# MemoryStream expandable with initial buffer

Tags: c#

I am trying to load some filestream into a memorystream. The source stream could be any stram, but the focus here is the destination stream.

The source has more than 3Gb.
I tryed 4 different approaches to this.

1)`fDest = new MemoryStream();` and then read 4K blocks into this. This takes forever com complete as the buffer must be resized on every step.

2)`fDest = new MemoryStream(int.MaxValue);` Got OutOfMemoryException on creation

3)`fDest = new MemoryStream(1073741823);` and then read 4K blocks into this. This loads fast but i get an OutOfMemory exception when the buffer needs to be resized.

4)`fDest = new MemoryStream(1073741824);`and then read 4K blocks into this. This works. The buffer resize is ok.

Can anyone point me some direction on why i got this behaviour with just one byte in diference on buffer size? I

Comment: will this answer help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397565/how-to-load-entire-stream-into-memorystream

Comment: Hi. the question here is not how to load. Is why this 1byte difference produces such behaviour... Thanks.