# C# - Unable to close file, resulting in 'file being used in another process' Exception

Tags: c#, file

I have a program that searches through a folder at a given path, and pulls out the paths of any files inside the folder or any subfolders inside it.
From here, it uses the individual file path to create an object of a custom class called `ImageData`. The method that handles this is shown below:

```
public void saveLatestImages(string chosenPath)
{
    //if there is a Pictures folder
    if (Directory.Exists(chosenPath))
    {
        //get number of files in folder
        int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(chosenPath).Count();

        //more than one file in folder
        if (fileCount > 0)
        {
            //create data structures to store file info
            //filePaths holds path of each file represented as a string
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(chosenPath);

            //for each file in Pictures...
            for (int index = 0; index < fileCount; ++index)
            {
                //get name of image at current index
                imageName = filePaths[index];
                //separate the part relating to the patient name (everything before (DD/MM/YYYY))
                string subSpecifier = imageName.Split('\\').Last();
                subSpecifier = subSpecifier.Split('_')[0];
                //add to root directory to form subfolder name
                subDirectory = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, subSpecifier);

                //subdirectory name formulated, check for pre-existing
                //subfolder does not exist
                if (!Directory.Exists(subDirectory))
                {
                    //create it
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectory);
                }
                //otherwise, file will be added to existing directory

                //take everything from end and folder\file division to get unique filename
                string fileName = imageName.Split('\\').Last();
                //add this to the existing subDirectory
                fileName = Path.Combine(subDirectory, fileName);

                //copy the image into the subfolder using this unique filename
                File.Copy(imageName, fileName, true); //true gives instruction to overwrite any existing file with the same path

                //construct new instance with created filename
                imageData.Add(new ImageData(fileName));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good.
The problem comes afterwards when the `ImageData` object created is being displayed on a `PictureBox` (using a Bitmap attribute). When this image is on the picture box, a number of options are available through buttons.
For example, one button is in place that would remove the `ImageData` object from the picturebox and delete the file.
This is done using the method below:

```
private void btnDeleteImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //imageData is List<ImageData> that contains all ImageData objects currently in use
    //imageSlider is the PictureBox where the images are displayed/////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //identify image currently on picturebox
    Image displayImage = imageData[displayImageIndex()].getThumbnailImage();
    //get the file path of this image
    string displayImagePath = imageData[displayImageIndex()].getImagePath();

    //move to next or previous image in list
    //then remove image that was just viewed

    //current image not last in list
    if (!(imageSlider.Image.Equals(imageData.Last().getThumbnailImage())))
    {
        displayImage = imageData[displayImageIndex() + 1].getThumbnailImage();
        //display the next image in the list
        imageSlider.Image = displayImage;

        //delete the image just moved on from from list
        imageData.RemoveAt(displayImageIndex() - 1);
        //delete the file path at this index in the paths list
        File.Delete(displayImagePath);
    }
    //current image is last in list
    else
    {
        displayImage = imageData[displayImageIndex() - 1].getThumbnailImage();
        //display previous image in list
        imageSlider.Image = displayImage;

        //delete the image just moved on from from list
        imageData.RemoveAt(displayImageIndex() + 1);
        //delete the file path at this index in the paths list
        File.Delete(displayImagePath); <--- ////ERROR OCCURS////
    }

    //check for prior and successive elements in list
    checkFirstLast(displayImage);
    updateImageInfo();
}
```

On the `File.Delete()` command, an exception occurs to inform me that the 'File cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process'.

Basically, the file is opened when it is brought into the program, and is never closed. This means that when I try to access the file to delete (or do something else with it), this cannot be done as the program currently stands.
I know that if I was using a `FileStream` object then I could call the `.Close()` method once the object was finished with. But seeing as all file access is done using string variables which are then used to create images, there does not seem to be an equivalent method available to me.

Does anyone know of any other way to implement this behaviour? If this is not going to be possible, is it possible to manage the image files using something like `FileStream`?

Any advice on where to go from here would be great.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Presumably you're creating `Bitmap` objects inside your `ImageData` class.  `Bitmap` objects keep the stream from which they're created open.  If you read all the file data into a `MemoryStream` (closing the `FileStream` when you're done reading) and create the `Bitmap` from that stream, you should be fine.

Comment: Your code looks very complicated and has much repeatings inside. But the code that creates the problem seems to be inside the 'ImageData' class and is not shown. It looks like it still has the fingers on the file, instead of loading it only. Can you show the code for leading the image?

Comment: Thanks for this, sounds like its what I could be looking for! Just a quick question, is a MemoryStream appropriate seeing as I'm only using the file path and no actual data from the file? And if so, how do I read the image data into the MemoryStream and read it out? Thanks @adv12

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397565/how-to-load-entire-stream-into-memorystream will give 3 possible ways to do that...

Comment: @marcuthh I've added an actual answer with the code you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you're probably creating `Bitmap` objects in your `ImageData` class, using [the constructor that takes a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the filename):

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(filename);
```

A `Bitmap` created with this constructor will create a `FileStream` from the file at the given path and will keep that `FileStream` open until the `Bitmap` is disposed, as mentioned in the documentation:

> The file remains locked until the Bitmap is disposed.

To get around this, you can instead build the `Bitmap` from a `MemoryStream` that you populate from the file yourself:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(stream);
```

This way, the stream the `Bitmap` keeps open is the `MemoryStream` you created rather than a `FileStream` that keeps the file locked.

Comment: Hi, I've just added these lines inside the `ImageData` method where I create the Bitmap. It compiles fine but I still get the same exception when I try to access the file again. Using the code you've given me, is there any kind of 'close()' method I might be missing?

Comment: Ignore previous comment, I have it working now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**The usual norm is -**

- Create a staging folder. Like a temp folder
- Make a copy of your file there
- Display the image from that temp file
- For each operation make a copy (1.jpg, 2.jpg)
- Finally when done, copy the latest final file back to the original folder
- Delete staging folder

**Advantages -**

- Original data is never lost
- Accidental corruption is very less
- Easy to have undo operations
- If you can't delete staging folder immediately, you can background job for this